# Enable specific UI pertaining to user credentials

Tags: javascript, firebase, underscore.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a list of paper-cards containing information posted by various users. This is what happens when users reach the web app.

1. They log in using their email and password
2. They post information about their item
3. Their email address is queried using firebase.auth().currentUser.email and is stored into the database together with the information that they posted.

So what I want to do is that get the email of the currently logged in user and then check if the email is the same as one of the key's child nodes and if they are the same, I want to enable a button that they can use to remove the post.

I tried the following code but does not work.

**EDITED CODE**

```
uploadsRef.on('value', function(snap) {
      var data = _.map(snap.val(), function (item, key) {
        item.key = key;
        var mail = item.email;
        console.log(mail);
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
          if(firebaseUser){
            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            var usr_mail = user.email;
            console.log(usr_mail);
            if(mail == usr_mail){
              item.hidden = 'disp';
            }
          }
          else{
            if(mail != usr_mail){
              item.hidden = 'hidden';
            }
          }
        });

        return item;
      });
      myFeed.splice.apply(myFeed, ['datas', 0, myFeed.length].concat(data));
    });
```

Comment: Looks like you're comparing the wrong variables here: `if(mail == user)` should be `if(mail == usr_mail)`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sorry for the typo there but still does not work...

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a very efficient mechanism for debugging your app. Can you set up a jsfiddle/jsbin that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Make sure you are waiting for the current user to resolve. You have to use onAuthStateChanged to wait for the state to be resolved, otherwise on load, the currentUser may be null.

Comment: @bojeil That solved the load issue but still not working...

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain that you're `this` is out of context. Try `myFeed.$.sold.classList.remove('hide')`.

Alternatively, bind a class to your element without manually using classList.

```
var myFeed = this;
var uploadsRef = firebase.database().ref('cattle/data');

uploadsRef.on('value', function(snap) {
  var data = _.map(snap.val(), function (item, key) {
    item.key = key;
    var mail = key.email;
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var usr_mail = user.email;
    if(mail !== usr_mail){
      item.hidden = 'hidden';
    }
    return item;
  });
  myFeed.splice.apply(myFeed, ['datas', 0, myFeed.length].concat(data));
});
```

So now that you have `item.hidden` set to 'hidden' for all non-owners...

```
<style>
  .hidden {display: none;}
</style>
<div class$="[[item.hidden]]"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks but still not working, I have tried to see if the code which is placed within the if(mail != usr_mail) condition is executed and it does, so there is no problem is verifying if the current user 's email matches the email of the person who posted the post. The main problem is in making the button hidden if they are non-owners and not hidden for owners, I even tried setting disp (display the element) if they are owners and by default hide the button if they are non-owners and it is still not working... This is the final piece of the puzzle in my project, pls help me...